# How to validate input for Int32.Parse() (without exceptions)

Tags: c#, parsing

~Caution~ The purpose of this question is academical and the answer HAS to use Int32.Parse()

Greetings

I want to know whether there is a way to "implement the exceptions" that Int32.Parse() throws using `if()`'s or something equivalent (without using exceptions. AT ALL & in any form).

Thanks in advance.
Mechanic

~EDIT1: Another way to put it, may be: is there a way to ensure secure input for int32.Parse() without using the exceptions class?

~EDIT2: It's not that I don't want the exception to be thrown at all, as was pointed out in the comments by @PeterDuniho, I know about `TryParse()`. I specifically said I want to use `Int32.Parse()`.

~EDIT3: An even better way to express my question would be: How can I ensure that the string passed as an argument to `Int32.Parse()` doesn't result in an exception?

~EDIT4: The reason I don't wish to use `TryParse()` is that if it fails the program will continue, while I want it to crush if the input (of `Int32.Parse()` ) is of incorrect form.

Comment: What do you mean by "implement the exceptions...without using exceptions"? All exceptions have to inherit `Exception`, and in any case an implemented exception is an exception regardless. So how could you without any? Are you just looking for the [`int.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Int32.TryParse(v=vs.110).aspx) method?

Comment: It's kinda hard to explain, but I basically mean that I "want to handle the exceptions that int32.parse() arises without using try&catch or force an exception to be thrown, or anything that has to do with exceptions. It's not practical I know, I just want to know if it can be done.

Comment: Another way to put it may be: is there a way to ensure secure input for int32.Parse() without using the exceptions class?

Comment: To handle an exception, you have to use `try`/`catch`. If you want to parse a number without an exception being thrown, use the `TryParse()` method I named in my first comment.

Comment: @Mechanic45 It helps if you actually read the comments. Peter's suggestion of `int.TryParse()` is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @mason
please see edits

Comment: What are you trying to do?  It seems like you've chosen a flawed solution and are trying to find out how to make it work instead of trying to find a non-flawed solution.  With more information we can probably help you find that non-flawed solution.

Comment: It looks like you want something like `if (TryParse(text, out result)) result = Int32.Parse(text);`. It doesn't have much sense, but it satisfies your request, apparently.

Comment: Its' purpose is solely academic. You could say, that I am trying to emulate the exception handling, but by checking input and NOT by handling the exception after it's been risen.

Comment: Other option is to manually validate the string. You can do that on your own or using a regular expression.

Comment: @Andrew I think you understood me correctly in your last comment, care to elaborate on that?

Comment: @Mechanic45 I saw your edits. And **still** `int.TryParse` fulfills your requirements. Have you tried it? Because that is **the** solution.

Comment: @mason Yes I have. Well I can put it this way then.. I want the program to crush (& burn :P) if the input is of incorrect form. If TryParse() fails, the program will continue to run, and I don't want that. The solution I am looking for, absolutely, has to use Int32.Parse().

Comment: @Mechanic45, but can your program use BOTH? Check the code in my first comment.

Comment: What do you mean, you want it to crash and burn? You want it to stop execution? Then if TryParse results in false, then feel free to end execution of the program, or provide a warning to the user that the value is incorrect. This **does not** mean that you have to use `Int32.Parse()`. `Int32.TryParse()` will allow you to do that, and avoid raising an exception which you stated as an explicit requirements in your question.

Comment: @mason Once more, I shall point out the 3 main things that I am looking for the answer. a) I want (NOT have) to use `Int32.Parse()` 
b) what I am trying to do is to validate its' input 
c) If (and only if) the input is incorrect I want the program to result in a crush. And by "crush" I mean ending with an ugly: Unhandled exception error

Comment: Then do `var passedCheck = int.TryParse(stringValue, out intValue); if(!passedCheck) { throw new ApplicationException("Crash. Burn.");}` You are completely over complicating this question. Explain your requirements *up front* and when the requirements don't make much sense, provide adequate explanation for them.

Comment: @mason No reason to get offended there. I said in earlier com's that it is hard to explain. Obviously I adapted my expressions while receiving feedback to better explain.

Comment: @Mechanic45 I am not offended. But I am trying to get this point to you across - you did not put enough effort into your question. If you *know* obvious answers and have a reason for why they won't work in your situation, then you should explain that. Because you've effectively created a moving goal post question, and put arbitrary restrictions on it. The `Int32.TryParse` function is **the way** to determine if an int will parse correctly without an exception. You later state an exception is okay, but don't explain why the exception from `Int32.Parse()` isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string stringValue = "123";
int intValue = 0;

bool check = int.TryParse(stringValue, out intValue);
```

If check is true the Parse is done correctly, if false the string can't parse to int.

Comment: Oh, well... So in the end, what was said since the first comment was the answer? I don't know why we discussed so much then!

Comment: @Andrew Basically I gave up trying to describe my problem, and just picked the answer with the most upvotes

Comment: Did you choose the answer that actually solved your problem? Wasn't a `Regex` what you needed?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a regular expression. For example:

```
string text = "-124";
int num;
Regex intRegex = new Regex(@"^\s*(\+|-)?\d+\s*$");
if (intRegex.IsMatch(text))
    num = Int32.Parse(text);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Unfortunately, the program has crashed and burned.");
```

In a big data batch I prepared, this regular expression had the same results as `TryParse`.

If you want a more specific regular expression, you can find more options [here](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=integer&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

Comment: Actually, this still isn't quite right because it only validates the typographic correctness. It doesn't range-check the number (which could be larger than `int.MaxValue`). Still, plus one from me, just for sticking with an obviously-flawed and impossible-to-pin-down question. :)

Comment: You are right. The easy way that comes to my mind to check that is with `Int64.Parse`, but that's a bit like cheating and the `Regex` wouldn't make sense then.

Comment: Frankly, the only way to meet the OP's requirements would be to go ahead and try to parse the text. The whole question was a bit on the ridiculous side, and it moved to the sublimely ridiculous when the OP accepted the one answer that was exactly what he said he _didn't_ want to do.